# Writing Spark Streaming Output to a Socket

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, apache-spark

I have a DStream "Crowd" and I want to write each element in "Crowd" to a socket. When I try to read from that socket, it dosen't print anything. I am using following line of code:

```
val server = new ServerSocket(4000,200);
val conn = server.accept()
val out = new PrintStream(conn.getOutputStream());
crowd.foreachRDD(rdd => {rdd.foreach(record=>{out.println(record)})})
```

But if use (this is not I want though):

```
crowd.foreachRDD(rdd => out.println(rdd))
```

It does write something to the socket.

I suspect there is a problem with using rdd.foreach(). Although it should work. I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code outside the DStream closure is executed in the driver, while the `rdd.foreach(...)` will be executed on each distributed partition  of the RDD.
So, there's a socket created on the driver's machine and the job  tries to write to it on another machine - that will not work for the obvious reasons.

`DStream.foreachRDD` is executed on the driver, so in that instance, the socket and the computation are performed in the same host. Therefore it works.

With the distributed nature of an RDD computation, this Server Socket approach will be hard to make work as dynamic service discovery becomes a challenge i.e. "where is my server socket open?". Look into some system that will allow you to have centralized access to distributed data. Kafka is a good alternative for this kind of streaming process.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful to understand. So to overcome this service discovery challenge, it modified the statement as: crowd.foreachRDD(rdd => {rdd.collect.foreach(record=>{out.println(record)})}). This will work (it worked) as it will collect the rdd partitions from the workers and send it to the driver which will write to socket. I hope this is the correct way. What do you think about this ....collect.foreach..... thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
crowd.foreachRDD(rdd => {rdd.collect.foreach(record=>{out.println(record)})})
```

Your suggested code in your comments will work fine but in this case you have to collect all records of RDD in driver. If number of records are small that will be ok but if number of records are larger than the driver's memory that will be become bottle neck. Your first attempt should always process data on client. Remember RDD is distributed on worker machines so that means first you need to bring all records in RDD to driver resulting in increased communication which is a kill in distributed computing. So as stated your code will only be ok when there are limited records in RDD.

I am working on similar problems and I have been searching how to pool connections and serialize them to client machines. If some body has any answers to that, will be great.

Answer (score 0):

[Here in the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) you have the answer!

You have to create the connection inside of the `foreachRDD` function, and if you want to do it optimally you need to create a "pool" of connections, and then bring the connection you want inside of the `foreachPartition` function, and call to the `foreach` function to send the elements through that connection. This is the example code for doing it in the best way:

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    // ConnectionPool is a static, lazily initialized pool of connections
    val connection = ConnectionPool.getConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    ConnectionPool.returnConnection(connection)  // return to the pool for future reuse
  }
}
```

In any case, check the other comments as they provide good knowledge about the context of the problem.